# How to Install libvirt-php?

Tags: installation, php

I am trying to install libvirt-php on my ubuntu server 11.10.
Could any one tell me what are the simplest steps to install libvirt-php ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libvirt-dev xsltproc libxml2-dev libxml2  
cd ~ 
git clone git://libvirt.org/libvirt-php.git libvirt-php  
cd libvirt-php  
sudo sh autogen.sh  
sudo ./configure  
sudo make  
sudo make install  
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To verify it's installed run the following command

```
php -m | grep libvirt
```

You should see `libvirt` in the output.

Comment: Could you tell me how to create a new domain? 
From PHP API Reference guide: (http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html)
I have seen these functions:

 `(i)   libvirt_image_create($conn, $name, $size, $format)`
 `(ii)   libvirt_domain_new($conn, $name, $arch, $memMB, $maxmemMB, $vcpus, $iso_image, $disks, $networks, $flags)`
 `(iii) libvirt_domain_create($res)`
 `(iv)  libvirt_domain_create_xml($conn, $xml)`
 
The problem I am facing is that i dont know the steps to create a new domain.
Either I have to create a new image first using libvirt_image_create .... or something else.