# Web-based Xen hypervisor

Tags: php, virtualization, webserver, xen

I want to make users able to create and manage virtual machines from a web-based interface.

1. I have installed Xen hypervisor on my Ubuntu machine
2. I have installed Apache webserver and all the other related stuff such as
   PHP, MySQL etc. and then I have tested the webserver and it's all running
   well
3. I have also installed a tool called virtual machine manager which belongs to Xen, so that I can create and manage a virtual machine

Now, I need to make this service (creating VMs) available on my webpage. So, I need to do some kind of PHP scripting to run commands on the virtual machine manager.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machine Manager interfaces with the **libvirt** daemon, not Xen, so if you are creating virtual machines within Virtual Machine Manager, then you will have to interface with libvirt from PHP in order to keep your virtual machines synchronous between the web interface and Virtual Machine Manager.

Apparently there is already a PHP module for handling this: https://libvirt.org/php/

[How to Install libvirt-php?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112246/how-to-install-libvirt-php)

Hope this helps